# How can I use the same JQuery function for 18 different classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, effects, jquery-effects

Code:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.boxes').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $btn = $(this);
    $btn.toggleClass('opened');

    var heights = $btn.hasClass('opened') ? 300 : 100 ;
    $('.boxes').stop().animate({height: heights });
  });
});
    </script>
```

I have 18 boxes that have the class `boxes`.  As you can imagine by clicking .boxes all 18 boxes open and close.  What I want to do is make sure that only the box that is clicked opens and closes rather than all of them. The 18 boxes have unique ids like box1, box2, box3, etc.

I am new to JS so to me a logical solution would be repeating the above code 18 times and use the id's unique to the boxes but I know that that's too much code repetition.  So, how can I make sure that only the box that is clicked is the one that opens and closes rather than all of them? Any tip will be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: You can use `$(this)` as you already did. So `$btn.stop().animate();` should do the trick.

Comment: It really just seems like you may need to read some basic tutorials.

Comment: @user2736012 What are some resources that I can use to solve these kinds of things?

Comment: Mostly Google. jQuery is currently massively popular. It's not at all difficult to find tutorials that will teach you how to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Give it a try now.

```
$(".boxes").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('opened');
    var heights = $(this).hasClass('opened') ? 300 : 100 ;

    $(this).stop().animate({height: heights}); //Show clicked box
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLZe9/)

Comment: I don't want to hide all boxes.  The boxes can remain there but only the box that is clicked should open and close.

Comment: You missed a usage of `$btn` ... It will be undefined when you are setting the heights var.

Comment: Hey @chad yes it is.  The only issue is that i have boxes underneath each other so when one opens and closes the space left when it was opened is sitll there.  what can i do about that?

Comment: I just realized something weird.  it works properly for the 3rd box (the last one in each row) but the first 2 it has that weird issue i mentioned above.

Comment: Just reduce the amount of space you set for the height when it is 'closed'. Change the `100` to like `25` and see if that's better. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rLZe9/1/

Comment: Also when the box opens I only want the vertical boxes underneath it to move down or up as the box opens not all the boxes horizontally.

Comment: For that, you can just set a div "wrapper" around each column and then make them `float: left;` in CSS. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/rLZe9/2/

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just change `$('.boxes')` to `$btn`? That will animate only the box that is clicked.

```
$btn.stop().animate({height: heights });
^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks! But if i use that when the box opens and closes it leaves huge empty space for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

changing `$('.boxes').stop().animate({height: heights });` to

```
$(this).stop().animate({height: heights });
```

will toggle only selected box. Check out fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/xSNYc/